# Why print statement calls **toString** method in java?

Tags: java, object-to-string

Why the following code segment auto calls **toString()** method?

### Code:

```
public class Demo {
   public Demo() {
    System.out.println(this); // Why does this line automatically calls toString()?
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Demo dm = new Demo();
   }
}
```

Comment: Then what would you want it to print?

Comment: Post runnable code. This is horribly mangled and invalid code.

Comment: This is a design decision. It would be also possible to as "why not to call" as toString is supposed to give string representation of the object.

Comment: @user2357112 dont u have java compiler or JDK?

Comment: Not one that recognizes `ublic` or `Syatem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`println` is overloaded for various types, the one you are invoking is:

`java.io.PrintStream.println(java.lang.Object)`

Which looks like this:

```
public void println(Object x) {
  String s = String.valueOf(x);
  synchronized (this) {
    print(s);
    newLine();
  }
}
```

And `String.valueOf` looks like this:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
  return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So you can see it calls `toString()` on your object. QED

Answer (score 1):

The designers of Java decided that they wanted to make it nice and simple to print any object at all, using statements like

```
System.out.println(something);
System.out.print(something);
someOtherPrintWriter.println(something);
```

without the programmer having to worry too much about what `something` actually was, so they made lots of versions of those methods.  But they couldn't anticipate every possible class that someone might want to print an object of.

But because every class extends `Object`, either directly or indirectly, all they needed to do was to make any instance of `Object` printable - which basically meant providing a way to convert any `Object` to a `String`.

They did that by including a `toString` method in the `Object` class, and making `print` and `println` use it.  Then, if anyone writes a class and needs it objects to be printed in a particular way, all they need to do is override `toString`, and then `print` and `println` will both do what the programmer expects.

Comment: hats off :) thnks alot !

Answer (score 0):

when System.out.println() is called, it tries to print something to the screen (obviously) The one thing that can be printed is a string, so every object that you give the method as parameter is going to be 'converted' to something that can be written to the output, so it calls the .toString() method

Answer (score 0):

The java code to print the Object

```
 public void println(Object paramObject)
      {
        String str = String.valueOf(paramObject); // Use valueOf method
        synchronized (this) {
          print(str);
          newLine();
        }
      }
```

valueOf  method of String

```
public static String valueOf(Object paramObject)
  {
    return paramObject == null ? "null" : paramObject.toString(); // toString() method is called
  }
```